# How can I change this code to SQL Server 2000 so that it distributes colors evenly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

How can I change this code to SQL Server 2000 so that it distributes colors evenly

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE
(
       Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Employees (Name) 
VALUES ('Sam'), ('John'), ('Jack'), ('April'), ('Sonny'), ('Jill'), ('Jane');

DECLARE @Colors TABLE
(
       Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Colors (Name) 
VALUES ('Red'), ('Green'), ('Blue');

DECLARE @ColorCount INT
SELECT @ColorCount = COUNT(*) FROM @Colors

;WITH Employees(SNumber, Name) AS
(
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SNumber, Name
       FROM @Employees
    ), 
    Colors(CNumber, Name) AS
    (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS CNumber, Name 
       FROM @Colors 
    )

SELECT E.Name, C.Name FROM Employees E
INNER JOIN Colors C ON 
       CASE 
       WHEN (E.SNumber % @ColorCount) = 0 
            THEN @ColorCount 
            ELSE E.SNumber % @ColorCount 
       END = C.CNUmber
```

Result:

```
Sam - Red
April - Red    
Jane - Red
John - Green
Sonny - Green
Jack - Blue
Jill - Blue
```

Comment: Are you sure it's sql-server 2000? AFAIK common table expressions only started on 2005...

Comment: @ZoharPeled He's looking to *convert* this script to SQL 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that aren't available in SQL Server 2000 should be converted:

- ROW_NUMBER: this can be done by populating the CTE in a temporary table with an IDENTITY to assign numbers
- CTE: populate the CTE's in temporary tables and use those in your final query.

Your script would look like the following:

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE
(
       Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Employees (Name) 
VALUES ('Sam'), ('John'), ('Jack'), ('April'), ('Sonny'), ('Jill'), ('Jane');

DECLARE @Colors TABLE
(
       Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Colors (Name) 
VALUES ('Red'), ('Green'), ('Blue');

DECLARE @ColorCount INT
SELECT @ColorCount = COUNT(*) FROM @Colors

CREATE TABLE #Employees(SNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #Employees(Name) SELECT Name FROM @Employees;

CREATE TABLE #Colors(CNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #Colors(Name) SELECT Name FROM @Colors;

SELECT E.Name, C.Name FROM #Employees E
INNER JOIN #Colors C ON 
       CASE 
       WHEN (E.SNumber % @ColorCount) = 0 
            THEN @ColorCount 
            ELSE E.SNumber % @ColorCount 
       END = C.CNUmber

DROP TABLE #Employees;
DROP TABLE #Colors;
```